# Pygame - Store surface as image

Tags: python, image, pygame, geometry-surface

This is just my second day at pygame, and I am not much aware about many functions. The following is a sample of what I am doing on my surface(window)

```
for c in nStations:
  pygame.time.wait( 20 )
  pygame.draw.circle( window, c.tColor, c.tPosition, c.iRadius )
  pygame.display.update()
```

This is looped for `n` number of circles(in a tuple) to be displayed. Now, this will be repeated a total of 5-6 times. I wish to store/save the surface window as an image(or sub-surface) and put it as a thumbnail/link at the top-right-corner of my window.

Is it possible? Or is `pygame` not a good library for this? I tried working on `cocos2d` too, but it's documentation is very poor as compared to `pygame`.

In case my question didn't make any-sense anywhere, please reply. I'll keep updating it.

**P.S.** I've seen [python.surface](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) library functions. and surface.copy seems to be what I am looking for, but can I store the surface as a thumbnail/image before copying and editing it further?

**EDIT**->After reading jsbueno's reply, what I did:

```
  tThumbs.append( pygame.transform.smoothscale( window, (32, 32) ) )
  # the above statement inside drawing-circle loop

i = 1
for thumb in tThumbs:
  window.blit( thumb, (1050, 36*i) )
  pygame.display.update()
  i += 1
  pygame.time.wait( 200 )
```

The above seems to work perfectly for me. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed - all drawing and transofmr functions in Pygame accept a "surface" as the first parameter. Actually, in pygame, a "surface" *is* an image.

The display window is just a surface as well - although a specialized one, whose contents are reflected on screen. But you can use `pygame.transform.smoothscale` to get a thumbnail copy of your screen surface, and then, the `blit` method of your screen object itself to paste it on screen.

If this is going to be done continuoulsy, the pasted corner ould also be replicated, like a video camera pointing to its own output - so the "right way" to do it is: keep yoru drawing ina  separate, in memory surface, blit it to the screen surface, and then blit the thumbnail above it.

Comment: I'd like to re-quote myself: > This is just my second day at pygame, and I am not much aware about many functions. Edited the question to reflect on what I did.

Comment: Please, do tell me if there's a shorter/quicker method to implement it.

Comment: How can I call the thumbnail back? For eg. clicking on a thumbnail must expand that surface back.

Comment: Pygame does not do "object hnadling" for you, neither does pure pygame it have widgets - you have to check for mouse events yourself, and see if a mouse click lands in teh thumbnail. You either rwrite this yourself, or you should look for a framework/widget library that works within pygame to handle it for you.